# Specified value has invalid HTTP characters with WebClient download

Tags: c#, http-headers, webclient, recaptcha

I have done a bit of research on this problem before. I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705797/specified-value-has-invalid-http-header-characters-parameter-name-name)  and it didn't help me. Basically I am trying to build a program to help people use a website, and I need to get the recaptcha V2 challenge images from google's recaptcha API. I keep getting a

> **Specified value has invalid HTTP characters**

when attempting to download the stream

```
 try
 {
      WebClientEx wc = new WebClientEx(cookieJar);
      wc.Headers.Add("Referer", recaptchaframe_url);
      wc.Headers.Add("UserAgent:", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)");
      Stream responsestream = wc.OpenRead("http://www.google.com" + challengeimageurl);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("This program was unable to download CAPTCHA image" + ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: I had a look at the HTTP header output as I have been debugging and Fiddler told me that "Specified value has invalid CRLF characters" when receiving a response from the server. Don't know if that helps debug the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this error by converting all manually set headers in the webclient to their .NET properties. (eg UserAgernt to HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent. It appears that it's useless to set header names manually.